# Aligning proofs from the proof package

Tags: vertical-alignment, arrays, proof-package

I am trying to align several proofs produced with the `infer` command from the [proof](http://www.logicmatters.net/resources/ndexamples/proofsty.html) package.

I want to be able to produce the following:
[image]

But I cannot align is this way. Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{cc}
    \vcenter{\infer[rule~name]{equation}{equation}}
    &
    conditions\ \vcenter{\infer[rule~name]{equation}{equation}}
    \\[1.5em]
    conditions\ \vcenter{\infer[rule~name]{equation}{equation}}
    &
    \vcenter{\infer[rule~name]{equation~maybe~longer}{equation}}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```

which produces the following:
[image]

Comment: So you want centering with respect to the inference lines?

Comment: Yes, exactly that.

Comment: You can do this *without* the `\infer` command...

Comment: Do you have several of these bizarre alignments or it's just a few shots?

Comment: This time, there are many more, not only four.

Comment: @Werner in other places of the document I need more complicated (nested) uses of the `infer` command, so it is better to use it also here to have an homogeneous representation.

Comment: @AlejandroDíaz-Caro: You could enlighten us with the "more complicated (nested)" views as well, and perhaps it'll be easy to replicate...

Comment: Well, not really. I use it many times in complicated ways that are already solved by this package, and only once with this strange align. Anyway, thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can measure the items and then set the condition and rule name parts pretending they have no width:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{proof,environ,array}

\newcommand\centerinfer[4]{%
 % #1=condition, #2=rule name, #3=lower, #4=upper
 \ifcenterinfermeasure
   $#1\ \vcenter{\infer{#3}{#4}}\ #2$%
 \else
   \llap{$#1$\ }\vcenter{\infer{#3}{#4}}\rlap{\ $#2$}%
 \fi
}
\newif\ifcenterinfermeasure
\NewEnviron{infertable}
 {\centerinfermeasuretrue
  \setbox0=\vbox{tabskip=0pt
    \renewcommand\\[1][]{\cr}%
    \halign{##&##\cr
    \BODY\crcr}
    \setbox0=\lastbox
    \setbox0=\hbox{\unhbox0 \unskip\setbox2=\lastbox\unskip\setbox4=\lastbox
      \global\dimen1=\wd4 \global\dimen3=\wd2 }
  }%
  \centerinfermeasurefalse
  \begin{tabular}{%
    @{}
    >{\centering$\displaystyle}p{\dimen1}<{$}
    >{\centering\arraybackslash$\displaystyle}p{\dimen3}<{$}
    @{}
  }
  \BODY
  \end{tabular}
}

\begin{document}
\[
\begin{infertable}
\centerinfer{}{rule~name}{equation}{equation} &
  \centerinfer{conditions}{rule~name}{equation}{equation}
\\[1.5em]
\centerinfer{conditions}{rule~name}{equation}{equation} &
  \centerinfer{}{rule~name}{equation~maybe~longer}{equation}
\end{infertable}
\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Amazing! This is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Alignment *without* the [`proof` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/proof) is possible with some "box manipulation" (phantoms and overlapping):

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\[
  \begin{array}{c}
    \phantom{\text{conditions}}\ \dfrac{\text{topA}}{\text{bottomA}}\ \rlap{\text{rule nameA}}\phantom{\text{rule name rule B}} \\ \\
    \text{conditions}\ \dfrac{\text{topBtopB}}{\text{bottomB}}\ \text{rule name rule B}
  \end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```