# center big proof in a vertical side

Tags: pdftex, proof-package

I'm an occasional user of latex, and I'm autogenerating code to make a proof with the proof package.

Now I have the problem, with big proof I'm not able to center it in the pdf and also avoid the overflow.

Any suggestion to solve this problem?

An example of proof with a bad pdf as result can be

```
% auto generate file, please not modify the content
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{proof}
\usepackage{lscape}
\pdfpagewidth 11in\pdfpageheight 12in\begin{document}
\begin{landscape}\centering\[
\infer[while]
{\langle while (x > 1) do (x := x - 1), [x:3] \rangle \to [x:1]}
{\infer[gt]
{\langle x > 1, [x:3] \rangle \to true}
{\infer[var]
{\langle x, [x:3] \rangle \to 3}
{}
&
\infer[num]
{\langle 1, [x:3] \rangle \to 1}
{}}
&
\infer[assign]
{\langle x := x - 1, [x:3] \rangle \to [x:2]}
{\infer[dec]
{\langle x - 1, [x:3] \rangle \to 2}
{\infer[num]
{\langle 1, [x:3] \rangle \to 1}
{}
&
\infer[var]
{\langle x, [x:3] \rangle \to 3}
{}}}
&
\infer[while]
{\langle while (x > 1) do (x := x - 1), [x:2] \rangle \to [x:1]}
{\infer[gt]
{\langle x > 1, [x:2] \rangle \to true}
{\infer[var]
{\langle x, [x:2] \rangle \to 2}
{}
&
\infer[num]
{\langle 1, [x:2] \rangle \to 1}
{}}
&
\infer[assign]
{\langle x := x - 1, [x:2] \rangle \to [x:1]}
{\infer[dec]
{\langle x - 1, [x:2] \rangle \to 1}
{\infer[num]
{\langle 1, [x:2] \rangle \to 1}
{}
&
\infer[var]
{\langle x, [x:2] \rangle \to 2}
{}}}
&
\infer[while]
{\langle while (x > 1) do (x := x - 1), [x:1] \rangle \to [x:1]}
{\infer[gt]
{\langle x > 1, [x:1] \rangle \to false}
{\infer[var]
{\langle x, [x:1] \rangle \to 1}
{}
&
\infer[num]
{\langle 1, [x:1] \rangle \to 1}
{}}}}}\]
\end{landscape}\end{document}
```

Comment: It is very hard to understood what I must center of your code. :-( Please, can you see if this question can help you? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/184714/aligning-proofs-from-the-proof-package

Comment: @Sebastiano I want to center the main rules, in the proof there is only one tree rule, but I can understand that it is difficult. Unfortunately the rules it is not well formatted.

Comment: Hi Vincenzo, but have you seen that is there another package ebproof? Peraphs it is very simple to center them. But being a Italian native speaker...often I have not understood the requests. :-( I'm sorry. My best regards from Sicily.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I want to add an answer to this question, I realize that one easy method to center the proof is to resize the pdf file.

I have some rules where I need to use the proof package to achieve my result.

The solution basically is to remove the package `lscape` and make use of the latex directive to resize the pdf, like the following `pdfpagewidth` and `pdfpageheight`

So the solution is the following code

```
    % auto generate file, please not modify the content
    \documentclass[10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{proof}
    % \usepackage{lscape} 
  \pdfpagewidth=800mm
  \pdfpageheight=150mm
  
  \begin{document}
    %\begin{landscape}
\centering\[
    \infer[while]
    {\langle while (x > 1) do (x := x - 1), [x:3] \rangle \to [x:1]}
    {\infer[gt]
    {\langle x > 1, [x:3] \rangle \to true}
    {\infer[var]
    {\langle x, [x:3] \rangle \to 3}
    {}
    &
    \infer[num]
    {\langle 1, [x:3] \rangle \to 1}
    {}}
    &
    \infer[assign]
    {\langle x := x - 1, [x:3] \rangle \to [x:2]}
    {\infer[dec]
    {\langle x - 1, [x:3] \rangle \to 2}
    {\infer[num]
    {\langle 1, [x:3] \rangle \to 1}
    {}
    &
    \infer[var]
    {\langle x, [x:3] \rangle \to 3}
    {}}}
    &
    \infer[while]
    {\langle while (x > 1) do (x := x - 1), [x:2] \rangle \to [x:1]}
    {\infer[gt]
    {\langle x > 1, [x:2] \rangle \to true}
    {\infer[var]
    {\langle x, [x:2] \rangle \to 2}
    {}
    &
    \infer[num]
    {\langle 1, [x:2] \rangle \to 1}
    {}}
    &
    \infer[assign]
    {\langle x := x - 1, [x:2] \rangle \to [x:1]}
    {\infer[dec]
    {\langle x - 1, [x:2] \rangle \to 1}
    {\infer[num]
    {\langle 1, [x:2] \rangle \to 1}
    {}
    &
    \infer[var]
    {\langle x, [x:2] \rangle \to 2}
    {}}}
    &
    \infer[while]
    {\langle while (x > 1) do (x := x - 1), [x:1] \rangle \to [x:1]}
    {\infer[gt]
    {\langle x > 1, [x:1] \rangle \to false}
    {\infer[var]
    {\langle x, [x:1] \rangle \to 1}
    {}
    &
    \infer[num]
    {\langle 1, [x:1] \rangle \to 1}
    {}}}}}\]
    %\end{landscape}
\end{document}
```